# How to change the label text in Angular Material File Upload

Tags: angular

I wanted to create a File Upload using angular material. 
I wanted to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-file-upload) one. 
One thing I want to change is the name **Selected File(s)** they offer this `[labelText]` property to change the text, but it actually just changes the label text.

Here is the code that I tested:

```
<mat-file-upload
  [labelText]="'Test'"
  [showUploadButton]="true">
</mat-file-upload>
```

Is there any way to change the text of **Selected Files(s)**?

Comment: And if you want to make [labelText] dynamic then use a variable [labelText]="var1" & in .ts
public var1 = "xyz".

Answer (score 0):

On your component.html that uses the `mat-file-upload` component, you will need to bind the `labelText` input binding to a new property called `labelText`.

```
<mat-file-upload
  [labelText]="labelText"   
  [showUploadButton]="true">
</mat-file-upload>
```

And on your component.ts, you will need to initialise the property with the desired text for the `labelText`

```
labelText:string = 'Custom Text Label';
```

I have made a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpzcu3?file=src/app/app.component.ts).